# How do I warn myself I'm about to send an email without an attachment in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013

Gmail has this amazing feature where it warns me I'm about to send an email that refers to an attachment but I haven't attached anything.  Is there a way to do this within Outlook 2010 as well?

I'm open to VBA scripts, Custom Rules, or Custom Add-Ins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlook 2013 has this feature built in so no need to add any customs scripts or add-ins.

Even though you ask for Outlook 2010 specifically [the following script](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/attachment-missing-from-outlook-message/) should work for 2010 and previous versions as well:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
   If InStr(1, Item.Body, "attach", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        If Item.Attachments.Count = 0 Then
          answer = MsgBox("There's no attachment, send anyway?", vbYesNo)
          If answer = vbNo Then Cancel = True
        End If
   End If
End Sub
```

This will give you an alert looking like the following:

[image: Horray!]

Pressing `yes` will send the email anyways while pressing `no` will halt sending the email thus giving you the ability to attach the attachment.

---

Here is an updated version.  Since replies contain previous messages, and there's not quick and easy way to determine where the reply body, and the quoted message begin/end, this will not prompt you on replies:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If InStr(1, Item.Subject, "RE:", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
       If InStr(1, Item.Body, "attach", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            If Item.Attachments.Count = 0 Then
              answer = MsgBox("There's no attachment, send anyway?", vbYesNo)
              If answer = vbNo Then Cancel = True
            End If
       End If
    End If
End Sub
```

It should also be noted that in both cases (my modified, and original) any original email with the word 'attach' will prompt you if you want to attach a file.